# how to show pagination with javascript?

Tags: javascript

This code show this type of pagination

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 next>>
```

I want show want show only first two digits and last And next button. Does first 2 values need to change on next click.

```
1 2 .... 12 next>>
```

This is my code:

```
_paginationOutput: function(currentPage, totalPages) {
            this.writeDebug('_paginationOutput',arguments);

            currentPage = parseFloat(currentPage);
            var output = '';
            var nextPage = currentPage + 1;
            var prevPage = currentPage - 1;

            // Previous page
            if( currentPage > 0 ) {
                output += '<li class="bh-sl-next-prev" data-page="' + prevPage + '">' + this.settings.prevPage + '</li>';
            }

            // Add the numbers
            for (var p = 0; p < Math.ceil(totalPages); p++) {
                var n = p + 1;

                if (p === currentPage) {
                    output += '<li class="bh-sl-current" data-page="' + p + '">' + n + '</li>';
                }
                else {
                    output += '<li data-page="' + p + '">' + n + '</li>';
                }
            }

            // Next page
            if( nextPage < totalPages ) {
                output += '<li class="bh-sl-next-prev" data-page="' + nextPage + '">' + this.settings.nextPage + '</li>';
            }

            return output;
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to check if the `p` variable is one of the pages you would like ignored.

EDIT:
To add the `...`, put it in the if condition, and check if you already printed the dot.

Try this code. Put this in the beginning of the `for` loop.

And, create a new variable called `dotsAdded` before the `for` loop.

```
if (p >= 2 && p < totalPages - 1) {

    if (!dotsAdded) {
        output += "...";
        dotsAdded = true;
    }

    continue;
}
```

That will continue the loop if and only if p is between 2 and the "second to last page."

Comment: thx, in the code, where i put the dot?  "..." (between 2 and last)